# powershell return only the nth element using split

Tags: powershell, parsing

How can I only return the second array element from this simple split:

```
$test="This,Home"
$test -split ","
```

Returns:

```
This
Home
```

How can I return only "Home"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get the second element from the list (indexed with 1)

```
$test="This,Home" 
($test -split ",")[1]
```

Comment: thanks I missed the () around the statement - that was the trick

Comment: Great, then please accept the answer and upvote it. Cheers :)